# Recomendation for a type of plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a data that has a 5 columns which stands for diferent methods that harbour how much of a chromosome is captured via diferent methods. the columns are **FACTOR** that stands for the category which data is grouped, **TOTAL** the length  of the chromosome, **METHOD** the method that captured that region, **FROM** and **TO** that shows the segment captured.

The general idea is to graph a range of the total length of the chromosome in order to see the overlap between methods across all chrmosomes.

As an example I leave this

**DATA INPUT**

```
a <- data.frame(FACTOR = as.factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4)),
                TOTAL = as.numeric(c(100,100,100,90,90,80,80,80,80,70)),
                METHOD = as.factor(c("A","B","C","A","B","A","B","C","A","C")),
                FROM = as.numeric(c(5,10,75,20,25,20,25,30,75,5)),
                TO = as.numeric(c(95,80,100,80,85,70,55,75,80,70)))
```

```
   FACTOR TOTAL METHOD FROM  TO
1       1   100      A    5  95
2       1   100      B   10  80
3       1   100      C   75 100
4       2    90      A   20  80
5       2    90      B   25  85
6       3    80      A   20  70
7       3    80      B   25  55
8       3    80      C   30  75
9       3    80      A   75  80
10      4    70      C    5  70
```

And I want to accomplished a graph similar to this (It's in paint I know and I'm sorry) The X axis will be for the **TOTAL** column and the Y axis will be **FACTOR**.

[image: Boxplot for Chromosome captured by different methods]

Comment: Something like `ggplot(a, aes(x = TOTAL, y = FACTOR)) + geom_segment(aes(xend = TO, yend = FACTOR, col = METHOD))`. The y arrangement of bars are not clear

Comment: I tried using ggboxplot, the thing there is that you'll have overlapped the segments. I want a boxplot so that the overlapping regions across the methods are very visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach. The basic idea is to use `geom_linerange` with thick lines (could alternatively use `geom_segment`) to plot your FROM and TO on the y axis and your FACTOR on the x axis and then flip it using `coord_flip`.

```
a$FACTOR <- factor(a$FACTOR, levels=c(4,3,2,1))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(a) +
  geom_linerange(aes(x=FACTOR, ymin=FROM, ymax=TO, colour=METHOD), size=3, position=position_dodge(width=0.5)) +
  coord_flip()
```

which yields:

[image]